# Ankane GroupDate issue with .minimum .maximum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using this gem https://github.com/ankane/groupdate I'm having issue when using anything else than `.count`

I have products where I store the price value every few hours in a PriceHistory table. The following query is working (Counting the number of price_histories for each day)

```
Product.first.price_histories.group_by_day(:created_at, range: 7.days.ago..Time.now).count
```

But this one is not (I'm trying to get the minimum price for each day)

```
Product.first.price_histories.group_by_day(:price, range: 7.days.ago..Time.now).minimum
```

How could I do that with or without the gem ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you give some example data, the result you expect, and the result you're getting instead? If there's an error message, what does it say? Can you show what SQL is being generated?

Comment: Error is : wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Answer (score 0):

The query was not correct it should have been

```
Product.first.price_histories.group_by_day(:created_at, range: 7.days.ago..Time.now).minimum(:price)
```